# Handling special characters in WebClient uploadString method using JSON

Tags: json, special-characters, webclient

I am using the WebClient.UploadString method to send a JSON object to a web service.
This is all working fine until the contents of the serialized JSON object contains a special character e.g. é, è, ê, ë, à or û

The error I get is a HTTP 400 on the receiving web service end and looking through logs shows that the entire json string is missing from the requests, almost like it fails to get sent.

Here is the code I am running to send the request:

    `var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item, Formatting.Indented);
    var response = WebClient.UploadString(GetRequestUri(partialUrl), "POST", json);
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response);`

So far I've tried:

1. urlencoding the entire string but this produces an error because the preceding "{ is also encoded (i think).
2. Setting the WebClient encoding to UTF8 which makes no difference (I think this is default anyway).

Any help of suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.